# Why is BitVec is missing the Serialize trait?

Tags: rust, traits, serde, bitvec

To familiarize myself with Rust, I took it upon myself to write a bloom filter that is backed by a `BitVec`. Part of that will include a `save` method that serializes the whole struct using serde and writes it to a file. Unfortunately, I get a compiler error when deriving the `Serialize` trait:

```rust
use bitvec::vec::BitVec;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct BloomFilter {
    n: u64,  // items added
    m: u32,  // slice size
    k: u32,  // number of slices
    buf: BitVec,  // buffer
    state: [u8; 8],  // random state
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `BitVec: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/bloom.rs:12:10
     |
12   | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
     |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `BitVec`
...
17   |     buf: BitVec,  // buffer
     |     --- required by a bound introduced by this call
```

My relevant `Cargo.toml` dependencies:

```ini
[dependencies]
bitvec = "1.0.1"
serde = { version = "1.0.196", features = ["derive"] }
```

This seems odd to me, since the [docs for bitvec 1.0.1](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/vec/struct.BitVec.html#impl-Serialize-for-BitVec%3CT%2C%20O%3E) mention `Serialize` (and `Deserialize`) as one of the traits implemented. Am I making some obvious mistake here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common practice for crates is to put `Serialize` and `Deserialize` behind a [Cargo feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html). Bitvec's features are listed [here](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/index.html#feature-flags), and you can enable the `serde` feature with this command:

```bash
cargo add bitvec -F serde
```

Or you can edit Cargo.toml manually:

```ini
[dependencies]
bitvec = { version = "1.0.1", features = ["serde"] }
```

Right now documentation doesn't let you know when something is behind a feature unless [the crate manually indicates it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/unstable-features.html#doccfg-recording-what-platforms-or-features-are-required-for-code-to-be-present), but hopefully in the future this will be documented automatically.